# Get second last url in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, url, redirect-url

How can we get the second last url in Magento 1.9?

I currently use this: `<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLastUrl();?>` To get the last URL.

But I want to get the second last URL after adding a product to the cart. Because the code above give in that case the url to add the product to the cart.

How can I get the url before that, so the second last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

> Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

to get the second last URL or Referrer URL. Or if you need it as a string

> Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])->getHeaders()[2]['value'];

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] would output the url or you may use

```
$previousurl = Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer() ? Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer()  : Mage::getUrl();
```

Comment: Thanks! But that does already set a redirect. I need only the URL.

Comment: Thanks again! I thought it worked well, but it seems that the previous url is wrong. It looks like is is being cached into Cloudflare. Any idea?

Comment: You can try deleting Cloudflare cache https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169246-How-do-I-purge-my-cache- followed by flushing Magento cache storage.